# why the answers are difference when using FTC1 and integrate then take derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

for example,

the derivatives of $\int_1^x\cos4(x+t)\,\mathrm dt$

using FTC1, the answer is $2\cos(8x)$

but integrate it and then take derivatives, the answer is $2\cos(8x) - \cos(4(x+1))$. Why?

Thanks

Seems I can rewrite the equation using trig identity.... 
$cos4(x+t) = cos(4x+4t) = cos(4x)cos(4t) - sin(4x)sin(4t) $

then I can apply FTC1 directly,

$ \int_1^x cos4(x+t)dt$ = cos(4x)$\int_1^x cos(4t)dt - sin(4x)$ $\int_1^x sin(4t)dt$ $ = 2cos(8x) $

but $2cos(8x) $ looks different to 2cos(8x)−cos(4(x+1))

Comment: You can apply FTC1 to take the derivative with respect to the upper integration limit $x$ only if the integrand does not depend on $x$.

Comment: but seems I can use some trigo formula to rewrite the equation and ' take out ' the 'x' terms and then I can use FTC1 directly, right?

Comment: $ \int_1^x cos4(x+t)dt$ = cos(4x)$\int_1^x cos(4t)dt - sin(4x)$ $\int_1^x sin(4t)dt$ is correct. After it is false. Don't forget that you are looking for the derivative with respect to $x$ , not for the integral itself.

Comment: oops,,, chain rule !! Thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

Since we have to differentiate with respect to a variable which appears in the integral itself AND in the limit of the integral, the calculus must respect the rules of differentiation for both.

To make it clear, separate both.

$$\text{Let :} \qquad f(x,y)=\int_1^y\cos4(x+t)\,\mathrm dt$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\cos4(x+y) \tag 1$$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\int_1^y\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\cos4(x+t)\,\mathrm dt = -4\int_1^y\sin4(x+t)\,\mathrm dt =  \left[\cos4(x+t)\right]_{t=1}^{t=y} =\cos4(x+y)-\cos4(x+1) $
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\cos4(x+y)-\cos4(x+1) \tag 2$$
Total differential :
$$\mathrm d f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm d x +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm d y = \big(\cos4(x+y)-\cos4(x+1)\big) \mathrm d x +\cos4(x+y) \mathrm d y$$

Case of $\quad y=x$ :
$$\mathrm d f(x,x)= \big(\cos4(x+x)-\cos4(x+1)\big) \mathrm d x +\cos4(x+x) \mathrm d x$$
$$\mathrm d f(x,x)= \big(2\cos8x-\cos4(x+1)\big) \mathrm d x $$

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\int_1^x\cos4(x+t)\,\mathrm dt=2\cos8x-\cos4(x+1)$$

Of course, people familiar with this kind of problem doesn't need such a tiresome detailed calculus. They straightforward apply the rules.

Comment: but how about my ways ? I edited the post, thanks!

Comment: Yes, in the present case you succeed to eliminate $x$ from the integrals themselves and let $x$ only in the bounds of the integrals. .If you continue your calculus without mistake, the result will be correct. But this method is not always possible, when the function of $x$ and $t$ cannot be expressed as a sum of separated functions of $x$ and of $t$..

Comment: Thanks for you clear approach !!